# Error while deploying Java based Webservice on Tomcat server 8.0

Tags: java, xml, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I am currently trying to deploy a Java based Web Service with Apache Tomcat server 8.0. When I try to deploy I get the following error :

```
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:379)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:1034)

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AxisServlet] and [cxf] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:308)**
... 32 more

  Aug 19, 2015 5:42:23 PM     org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser parseWebXml

SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/D:/APP_NAME/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/beA_WS/WEB-INF/web.xml

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/APP_NAME/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/beA_WS/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 49; columnNumber: 21; Error at (49, 21) : The servlets named [AxisServlet] and [cxf] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AxisServlet] and [cxf] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:308)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:379)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:1034)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:956)
... 25 more
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s) -->
```

Since the error is with having two mapped servlets [AxisServlet] and [CXF], I tried to comment out one in the web.xml file (WEB-INF/web.xml) and deploy and the new error is :

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
```

I do not know if I am missing some thing, Please help me in this regard.

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>beA_WS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
     <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
     <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
     <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
     <display-name>cxf</display-name>
     <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
     <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlet `AdminServlet` has a path which would be covered by servlet `AxisServlet`, you need to change the path for the `AdminServlet` to something else such as `/_admin_servlet`

The second error you are getting is because of library initialization, I'm not a Spring expert neither fan. Just check if all the dependencies are set for all stuffs, sometimes library `a` dependence on lib `b`, where `b` is missed, and exception for loading lib `a`

The good practice is make the container isolated/dedicated for one particular business/project if you can, and simply place all the libraries required under library-specified folder(`lib` most of the times)